# How to remove a part of string effectively

Tags: c#, .net

Have a string like A=B&C=D&E=F, how to remove C=D part and get the string like A=B&E=F?

Comment: Be more specific: which assumptions are made on input string and which rules determine the part to be removed.  
Just this one example would give you trivial and non-helpful suggestions like "don't remove anything and use a constant string "A=B&E=F" instead".

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Either just replace it away:

```
input.Replace("&C=D", "");
```

or use one of the solutions form your previous question, remove it from the data structure and join it back together.

Using my code:

```
var input = "A=B&C=D&E=F";
var output = input
                .Split(new string[] {"&"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(s => s.Split('=', 2))
                .ToDictionary(d => d[0], d => d[1]);

output.Remove("C");
output.Select(kvp => kvp.Key + "=" + kvp.Value)
      .Aggregate("", (s, t) => s + t + "&").TrimRight("&");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
using System.Web; // for HttpUtility

NameValueCollection values = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("A=B&C=D&E=F");
values.Remove("C");
values.ToString();  // "A=B&E=F"
```

Comment: It looks like the question is about URL parameters, so I like that you're pointing them towards HttpUtility

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to give a clearer example to make sure it's something for the situation, but something like this should do that:

```
var testString = "A=B&C=D&E=F"
var stringArray = testString.Split('&');
stringArray.Remove("C=D");
var output = String.Join("&", stringArray);
```

Something like that should work, and should be pretty dynamic

Answer (score 1):

You can either split() and manually join (depending how the data looks like) or simly use string.Replace(,string.empty)

Answer (score 1):

Split it on the `&` separator, exclude the `C=D` part by some mechanism, then join the remaining two? The `String` class provides the methods you'd need for that, including splitting, joining and substring matching.

Answer (score 1):

```
string xyz = "A=B&C=D&E=F";
string output = xyz.Replace("&C=D","");
```

Output: A=B&E=F