# How To remove the http://www from the any given url in c#

Tags: c#

I need help to remove

`http://www.` or `www.` from the any **URL**. For example

```
http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
```

for the above all I need `stackoverflow.com/questions/ask`

Comment: So wha's not working with your code?

Comment: You can read about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027853/how-to-remove-a-part-of-string-effectively

Comment: look at your HttpRequest object, it's in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really really simple

```
var url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask";
url = url.Replace("http://","").Replace("www.","")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
string strNew= str.Replace("http://","").Replace("www.","");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the Url to String, then using the `Replace()` method on it to replace a part of it with some other text or a empty string. Here would be the example:

```
var url = Request.Url.ToString(); 
/* if you want to get the URL first, then try the above code to get URL
 * otherwise, just use a simple string object */
url.Replace("http://www.", "").Replace("www.", "");
```

Now when you'll execute the code, you'll get the URL without the `http://` or `www.` part.

Also, note the double usage of `Replace()` method. That would replace them both.